# How to store multiple value in for-loop? php

Tags: php, for-loop

System details: A customer can buy a number(from 0000 to 9999) with a price, the system will make a keep record about every times when a customer buy a number. At the end of the day, the system should return the number with the highest and lowest accumulated price.

For example,
Alex buy number 1234 for price $50,
Jasmine buy number 5555 for price $100,
John buy number 1234 for price $100,
now, the system should display the price for number 1234 is $150 and number 5555 is $100.

My idea of doing this is create an array[10000] to hold 10000 number and every number have its own variable call '$price' .

But my question is how an array can hold both variable 'number' and 'price'?

```
$numbers = array(10000);
$price = $price;

//when user insert a number
    for(i=0000;i<=9999;i++){
        number=array[i];
        
//user can insert a price for every number inserted
        while(number>0){
            <input value="" name="price">
        }
//the for loop will return every number and its profit when ended.
    return $number , $price;
    }
```

is this the correct way to do this?

Comment: `number=array[i];` needs to be `$number[] = array[i];`

Answer (score 0):

Creating the initial array is easy:

```
$numbers = [];
```

The keys are the numbers, and the values are the total price paid for that number (assuming you don't need to store the price each person paid, but just the "total" price paid for each number):

```
// When a person buys number $n for $price:
$numbers[ $n ] += $price;
```

To display the total price paid for each number:

```
foreach ( $numbers as $n => $price ) {
  echo "Number $n cost a total of $price\n";
}
```

To determine the cheapest and most expensive numbers (and their prices), sort the array by price (i.e. value):

```
asort( $numbers, SORT_NUMERIC );
```

Then, the cheapest number is the first one:

```
$cheapest_number = array_key_first( $numbers );
$cheapest_price = $numbers[ $cheapest_number ];
```

And the most expensive is the last:

```
$most_expensive_number = array_key_last( $numbers );
$most_espensive_price = $numbers[ $most_expensive_number ];
```